# tensorflow.python.util.tf_export.symbolalreadyexposederror: symbol name_scope_v1 is already exposed as ()

Tags: python, django, keras, theano, pythonanywhere

I am trying to set up theano backend for keras in my django server. And i got this error. I have no idea about this error please help me.

```
(func.__name__, getattr(func, api_names_attr)))  # pylint: disable
```

here is link for full error i got in my server [error log](https://pastebin.com/DUjgKpL6). I am using pythonanywhere hosting.